# Devcon disable not working in Windows 8.1

Tags: devcon

I'm trying to make a simple script that disables my touchpad fast. I found tons of articles about devcon, I downloaded it, and I always get an error as I'm trying to do it, no matter which version of devcon I'm using.

```
C:\Windows\system32>devcon disable ACPI\ETD0108
ACPI\ETD0108\4&30E2CFCB&0                                   : Disable failed
No devices disabled.
```

I'm using Windows 8.1. Has anyone faced the same problem, or knows the solution?

Edit: I've tried to disable my USB mouse, with success. Then why is it a problem only of my touchpad?

Thanks,

dobragab

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I will point out that it seems like you might be using the 32 bit version on a 64 bit system. I've seen notes online that this will have limited functionality, not always letting you disable/enable things. To get the 64 bit version you will have to get it as [noted here](http://superuser.com/questions/305685/devcon-exe-not-working-in-windows7-x64)

Comment: Yes I found that thread, I can assure you that I use the correct version. (I can disable everything else with devcon, except touchpad.) I guess it just cant be disabled, because it is also impossible to disable from Device Manager.

Original Asus keyboard and touchpad drivers had the hotkey to disable it, but I replaced that topchpad driver with Elantech driver, because the old one is crap. With new driver the hotkey isnt working. I have no idea if the old driver made it impossible to disable for other devices, or it is completely impossible. Anyway, I gave up.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm on an HP Envy but same exact story. I can't get the right version working either (though with a different error than yours). I even tried the [DeviceManagement powershell](Error calling SetupDiCallClassInstaller) module to no luck (getting `Error calling SetupDiCallClassInstaller` when trying to disable).

Answer (score 2):

You need to comment out the "&" try using ^& also only use the longer line

C:\Windows\system32>devcon disable ACPI\ETD0108\4^&30E2CFCB&0

Answer (score 1):

You need the devcon.exe for windows 8.1
[Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx)
which can be downloaded from [Download the Windows ADK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365)

Comment: After install all WDC, locate yhe devcon.exe in your Kit folder and copy into system32 folder. You uninstall all package and devco works perfectly.